# Cannot use port 80 for my application

Tags: process, windows-7, port, listen

I have an application called NTWebService, and this uses port 80 to listen to my computer. However, When I run the application, I get an error:

> Listen failed.

More exactly,

> Initializing sockets... 
>   Sockets Initialized OK 
>   Starting Listen thread. 
>   Starting Threads 
>   .....CS:Listen: bind failed: 10013 
>   Listen Failed

is shown on the window that opens when I run the application.

When I typed `netstat -nao` on command prompt, I found that a process with PID 4 is using port 80, and that that process is System and I cannot delete it. When I did some research, most of them had said

1. On Control Panel, open *Programs and Features*
2. Click on *Turn Windows features on or off* on the left pane
3. Locate *Internet Information Services*
4. Uncheck the textbox for *World Wide Web Services*

However, when I checked this, it had been unchecked. I basically had nothing to do on it. I also tried another way:

1. Click on Start button and right click on *Computer*
2. Click *Manage* to open Computer Management
3. Click on *Services and Applications* from left pane and double-click *Services*
4. Locate *World Wide Web Publishing* and turn it off

However, I don't even see *World Wide Web Publishing* on the list, so again, I could not do anything about this.
I also don't think I can tell NTWebService to change the port it listens on. Is there any other good way for this application to listen on port 80?

Comment: What's the actual error code?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: What happens if you navigate with your browser to port 80 on your PC?

Comment: Also which webserver software are you using? Make also sure you are running it as superuser.